# Не выводится страница ошибки Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Пишу сайт на yii2. В конфиге имею такую настройку

```
'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ]
```

В SiteController.php есть такое

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ]
    ];
}
```

И так же определен экшин

```
public function actionError(){
    return $this->render('error');
}
```

Но вывод этой страницы не работает, выводится просто без стилизации описание ошибки. Даже если убрать последние 2 части - тоже самое. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Если ручками ввести адрес site/error выводится данная страница?

Comment: спасибо, не додумался проверить( натупил с правами доступа